# Is it possible to retype object from object to integer

Tags: java, parsing, object, arraylist

i am facing problem with the retyping the object to integer.

I have the object Car with 2 string attributes. First attribute is ID.
I retyped ID from string to integer

```
ArrayList<Car> intList = new ArrayList<Car>(); // already filled with objects 

ArrayList<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for(Car tempInt : items){   
intList.add(Integer.parseInt(tempInt.getID()));
}
Collections.sort(intList); // i sorted id's
```

Can i retype the integer back to Car object?

```
for (ItemObject temp : intList) { // HERE I GET THE ERROR

if(temp instanceof Car){
System.out.println("ID : "+((Car)temp).getID())
        }}
```

Is this possible? I need sort objects.
Thanks.
S

Comment: There's no such thing as to "retype" an object, at least not in Java since it uses strong typing. You can parse a numeric String to int or other number, but need a good reason to do so. Also, most of the time, it's not a good idea to treat id numbers as "numbers" since they do not behave as numbers -- you never add them, subtract them or multiply them. Why not simply leave them as Strings? Next: what are you trying to achieve with all this code? Likely there's a better way such as perhaps by using a `Map<String, Car>` or some such, again all depending on your needs.

Comment: I read the values from file line by line add the values to array.Than Pass array values to constructors and ad the objects to the arraylist.What i need to do is sort array list due to ID and write it back to the file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are fundamentally misunderstanding which objects are which in this scenario. When you create your `ArrayList<Integer>` you do not magically preserve any information about which cars those integers were connected to.

I *think* what you want to do is sort your list of `Cars` by id, correct? In that case, what you want is a `Comparator`: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Here is an example of sorting using a `Comparator`:

```
ArrayList<Car> cars = ...//Filled with cars
Comparator<Car> carSorter = new Comparator<Car>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(Car a, Car b) {
    return a.getID() - b.getID();
  }
};
Collections.sort(cars, carSorter);//After this line, cars will be in order
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't do it this way at all. If you instead allow cars to be able to compared to each other (by storing the id as an `Integer`, the `Car`s can sort themselves. Do it like this:

```
public class Car implements Comparable<Car> {
    private String id;
    private String otherString;
    private Integer intId; // this is new

    public Car(String arg0, String arg1) {
        // Add this line to constructor
        intId = Integer.parseInt(id);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Car arg0) {
        return intId.compareTo(arg0.intId);
    }
}
```

Then, just do:

```
Collections.sort(carList);
```